# How to create a button for moving the window without the main button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm french so **my English is a little bit bad** so don't pay attention.
I have made a `tkinter` calculator and for that I have delete the top of the window where the title and close button are situated and replace it by a canvas and it looks very nice, but I can no longer move the window on my screen, **the window stays in the upper-left corner**, and I can't move it in any way...I hope someone would have an idea.

For deleting the top of the window I have used  `win.overrideredirect(1)`.

I have tried something but this doesn't work:

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()

def coordsSouris(event):
    # win.geometry()
    print(event.x, event.y)
    win.after(100, coordsSouris)

can = tk.Canvas(height = 400, width = 400)
can.pack()

can.bind("<Button-1>", coordsSouris)

win.mainloop()
```

The function misses the arg `event` and I can't give this argument with `after()`...

I have another idea: Is it possible to place the tittle bar in front of my canvas and hide it and cute i when it was in front of my exit button and menu ? so we doesnt see it but it work normaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have find **the solution** and its work **perfectly** !!!

I hope it will **help** people to do a **personalized title bar**!!!

my code :

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
x = 0
y = 0
def move_window(event):
    # global x, y
    print(x, y)
    #event.x_the_name_of_the_widows is false you have to use x_root
    #event if your page is called win or ...
    root.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root - x, event.y_root - y))

root.overrideredirect(True) # turns off title bar, geometry
root.geometry('400x200+200+200') # set new geometry

# make a frame for the title bar
title_bar = Frame(root, bg='white', relief='raised', bd=2)

# put a close button on the title bar
close_button = Button(title_bar, text='X', command=root.destroy)

# a canvas for the main area of the window
window = Canvas(root, bg='black')

# pack the widgets
title_bar.pack(expand=1, fill=X)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# find the position of the cursor on the window and not on the screen

def set_xy(event):
    global x,y
    x=event.x_root - root.winfo_x()
    y=event.y_root - root.winfo_y()
    # print(x,y)
    return x,y;

title_bar.bind('<1>',set_xy)

# bind title bar motion to the move window function

title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set root `.geometry( Width x Height + X + Y )`.
keep Width & Height the same, just change X & Y parameters.

[image: buttons]

---

**Edit:**  Yeah, that's a little more complicated.  You need to store the initial drag position, then subtract it from subsequent events.  Clear value once the button has been released.  You also want to set min / max values to make sure it isn't going off the screen.

[image: lrduX]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter 

Width, Height, = 100, 33
Xpos, Ypos = 20, 20
dragposX, dragposY = 0, 0

root = tkinter .Tk() 
root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}+{Xpos}+{Ypos}')
root .overrideredirect( 1 )  ##  no titlebar

Screenwidth = root .winfo_screenwidth()
Screenheight = root .winfo_screenheight()
Xmax = Screenwidth -Width
Ymax = Screenheight -Height

fontname = 'ariel'
fontsize = 8
fontstyle = 'normal'
font = fontname, fontsize, fontstyle

def left():
    global Xpos ; Xpos -= 5
    if Xpos < 0:  Xpos = 0
    root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}+{Xpos}+{Ypos}')

def right():
    global Xpos ; Xpos += 5
    if Xpos > Xmax:  Xpos = Xmax
    root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}+{Xpos}+{Ypos}')

def up():
    global Ypos ; Ypos -= 5
    if Ypos < 0:  Ypos = 0
    root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}+{Xpos}+{Ypos}')

def down():
    global Ypos ; Ypos += 5
    if Ypos > Ymax:  Ypos = Ymax
    root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}+{Xpos}+{Ypos}')

def drag( event ):
    global Xpos, Ypos, dragposX, dragposY
    if dragposX == 0 and dragposY == 0:
        dragposX = event .x
        dragposY = event .y

    Xpos += event .x -dragposX
    Ypos += event .y -dragposY
    if Xpos < 0:  Xpos = 0
    if Ypos < 0:  Ypos = 0
    if Xpos > Xmax:  Xpos = Xmax
    if Ypos > Ymax:  Ypos = Ymax
    root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}+{Xpos}+{Ypos}')

def clear( event ):
    global dragposX, dragposY
    dragposX, dragposY = 0, 0

left_button = tkinter .Button( root, text='<', font=font, padx=2, pady=0, bg='blue', activebackground='lightblue', command=left )
left_button .grid( row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=4 )

right_button = tkinter .Button( root, text='>', font=font, padx=2, pady=0, bg='blue', activebackground='lightblue', command=right )
right_button .grid( row=0, column=1, padx=1, pady=4 )

down_button = tkinter .Button( root, text='v', font=font, padx=2, pady=0, command=down )
down_button .grid( row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=4 )

up_button = tkinter .Button( root, text='^', font=font, padx=2, pady=0, command=up ) 
up_button .grid( row=0, column=3, padx=1, pady=4 )

close_button = tkinter .Button( root, text='X', font=font, padx=2, pady=0, bg='red', activebackground='pink', command=root.destroy )
close_button .grid( row=0, column=4, padx=1, pady=4 )

root .bind( '<B1-Motion>', drag )
root .bind( '<ButtonRelease-1>', clear )

root .mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks but i really can't have the same things like normaly ?

Comment: Well, you can customize them to appear any way you want.  Just set button width & height, then use < > ^ v X characters instead of text.  ...or images.

Comment: maybe do a tracker of the mouse when i click on my canvas which are situate a the top of the windows and add the position to the .geometry ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified method for moving canvas.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def realcenter( o, w, h ) ->'o(w,h) centered on screen':
    x = o.winfo_screenwidth( ) - w
    y = o.winfo_screenheight( ) - h
    o.geometry( '{0:d}x{1:d}+{2:d}+{3:d}'.format( w, h, int( x/2 ), int( y/2 ) ) )

def restore( ev ):
    master.overrideredirect( 0 )

def unrestore( ev ):
    master.overrideredirect( 1 )

master = tk.Tk()
sizew, sizeh = 400, 400
canvas_box = tk.Canvas(master, width=sizew, height=sizeh )
canvas_box.grid(row=0,column=0)

master.geometry( '400x400' )
realcenter( master, 400, 400 )

master.update_idletasks()

master.overrideredirect( 1 )

master.bind( '<F1>', restore )
master.bind( '<F2>', unrestore )

tk.mainloop()
```

I've included a window centering function
A slight modification to make it 2.x compatible.

Comment: thank you its work ! I have another idea: Is it possible to place the tittle bar in front of my canvas and hide it and cute i when it was in front of my exit button and menu. so we doesnt see it but it work normaly

Comment: You mean you want your buttons to 'replace' the normal title bar then hide them when the real title bar is restored?

Comment: i have a canvas that i use instead of the title bar where i have an exit button and a little menu.I have made that because the title bar is ugly.so i want that this canvas can move the window like the title bar. so if its possible I can hide the title bar to see my canvas behind her and when i click on my canvas it click on the title bar because she is in front of so I can move the windows normaly.

Comment: When `overrideredirect` is enforced you can not move the window but if you take @Doyousketch2 neat buttons and place them in a `Frame` or `LabelFrame` then it's possible to use `grid_forget` to hide it when the normal title bar appears.